# Неправильное сообщение при голосовании за восстановление ответа

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, статус-отложено, локализация, восстановление-сообщений

При нажатии на кнопку «восстановить» у удалённого сообщения, появляется сообщение: «Ваш голос за удаление учтен».

Должно быть, как я понимаю: «Ваш голос за восстановление учтён».

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Про «не давала создать вопрос» – это старая тема, поднималась уже не раз. Многим не нравится формулировка, но новую и хорошую пока что не придумали. [Непонятные сообщения системы для слишком короткого заголовка и текста](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550)

Comment: А можете дать ссылку на этот вопрос, на котором было сообщение такое?

Comment: @NickVolynkin да любое. Например это http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1763/15479

Comment: Багу куча лет, на метемет известно о нем?

Comment: @АндрейNOP маловероятно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подтверждаю, в первый раз показывается именно такое сообщение. Нужная строка уже переведена ([Tx: 171](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261744?key=b545a79174fcb1a87d8704e425118dab)):

> Your delete vote has been recorded
>
> Ваш голос за удаление <s>учтен</s> учтён

Однако, вместо неё используется другая ([Tx: 162](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261735?key=2493fb6073c1ebbb0e00003b37c8a535)):

> Your undelete vote has been recorded
>
> Ваш голос за восстановление <s>засчитан</s> учтён

Зачеркиванием я обозначил только что внесённые правки. Похоже, перевод в норме, но система берёт не ту строку. Это баг в локализации движка, его нужно передать разработчикам.